# Linking CXX executable RemoteZynAddSubFx

Tags: compiling, make, executable, ld, lmms

I'm trying to build the latest version of LMMS v1.0.0 and I'm running into this error

Linking CXX executable RemoteZynAddSubFx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [plugins/zynaddsubfx/RemoteZynAddSubFx] Error 1
make[1]:**  [plugins/zynaddsubfx/CMakeFiles/RemoteZynAddSubFx.dir/all] Error 2
make: ** [all] Error 2

What I gather is it can't find these 3 things to link to? Where do I find them and then link them?

Much appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZynAddSubFX links to these libraries and they are a hard-dependency as outlined in the [build tutorial](https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/wiki/Compiling-lmms) (see the `Or, manually:` block).

```
apt-get install libxft-dev libxinerama-dev
```